# Распарсить json

Tags: json, php, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый вечер.
Так как я не очень силен в php однако пишу сейчас vk-api приложение, хотелось бы узнать следующее: как в PHP можно распарсить json? Знаю что через json_decode, но как именно не знаю. Хотелось бы записать строчку id в переменную.

Сам JSON:

```
response: [{
id: 123456,
first_name: 'First',
last_name: 'Name'
}]
```

Comment: json_decode даст вам массив в котором будут assoc. почитайте [пожалуйста руководство по php](http://www.php.net//manual/ru/index.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$responseJson = "[{ id: 123456, first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Name' }]"; // ваш пример строки
$response = json_decode($responseJson, true); // преобразование строки в формате json в ассоциативный массив 
$id = $response[0]['id']; // ваш искомый id
```

Документация:

- [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
- [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)
- [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)
- [работа с массивами](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.array.php)