# Распарсить json в PHP и передать в JS

Tags: json, php, javascript

Есть многомерный массив в виде JSON:

```
   {
   "date2" : "20140616",
   "min" : {
      "denial" : 0,
      "visits" : 4,
      "new_visitors_perc" : 0.4343,
      "page_views" : 12,
      "visit_time" : 70,
      "depth" : 1.733,
      "new_visitors" : 3,
      "visitors" : 4
   },
   "max" : {
      "denial" : 0.2988,
      "visits" : 396,
      "new_visitors_perc" : 0.75,
      "page_views" : 1017,
      "visit_time" : 157,
      "depth" : 3,
      "new_visitors" : 226,
      "visitors" : 354
   },
   "data" : [
      {
         "wday" : 0,
         "denial" : 0,
         "visits" : 4,
         "new_visitors_perc" : 0.75,
         "page_views" : 12,
         "date" : "20140616",
         "visit_time" : 82,
         "depth" : 3,
         "new_visitors" : 3,
         "visitors" : 4,
         "id" : "20140616"
      },
      {
         "wday" : 6,
         "denial" : 0.2045,
         "visits" : 176,
         "new_visitors_perc" : 0.5542,
         "page_views" : 393,
         "date" : "20140615",
         "visit_time" : 104,
         "depth" : 2.233,
         "new_visitors" : 92,
         "visitors" : 166,
         "id" : "20140615"
      },
      {
etc
```

Необходимо вывести в итоге в таком виде:

```
        "date": "значение",
        "visits": значение,
        "pageviews": значение
```

И так для каждого из элементов.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Обойти в цикле массив data и выводить нужные значения.

Comment: А как это сделать в виде кода?

Можете показать пример или рассказать, что почитать?

А если еще сложнее: как вывести это всё в обратном порядке? Т.е. чтобы последний элемент в массиве был первым в ответе?

Comment: Как распарсить - уж потрудитесь поискать тут же - http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/json/. По несколько раз на дню спрашивают.

>  Т.е. чтобы последний элемент в массиве был первым в ответе?

Обычный цикл `for`, где `i` меняется от `длина_массива - 1` до `0`, уменьшаясь на 1 на каждом шаге. Обращаемся к элементу массива с индексом `i` и выводим, что нужно.

Comment: ваша структура JSON настолько непонятна, что давать конкретный ответ просто невозможно. Поэтому рекомендую просто прочитать нужные разделы в документации по PHP, __повторить все их примеры кода и понять их__, затем проверить на своих данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/328578#328639

Пример вывода массива из PHP в javascript

```
<?php
$pagestats = array( // массив в PHP
    array(
        "date": "значение",
        "visits": "значение",
        "pageviews": "значение",
    ),
    // ...
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.pagestats = <?php echo json_encode($pagestats) ?>; // вывод массива из PHP в Javascript в глобальную область видимости

// или так
function b() {
    var pagestats = <?php echo json_encode($pagestats) ?>; // в локальную переменную
}
</script>
```

Дополнительно:

- как развернуть массив [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php)
- как отсортировать в нужном порядке с помощью произвольной функции [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php), а вообще функций сортировки [очень много](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php)